# Python virtualbox API

Tags: python, virtualbox

Please give some suggestions on how to control virtualbox from commandline from a python program using python virtualbox API. If you know any useful website, please give its address

Answer (score 1):

Looking into some [PyVB Source](http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb/pyvb.vb-pysrc.html) and [API doc](http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb/) would be good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound really snide but: [Let me Google that for you](http://tinyurl.com/yasjlvr)

... though I have to admit that I had to try the [fourth link from my results](http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb/) to find something that looked like it might actually be useful.  Also it looks like you'll get quite a bit more from the "view source" than from the docstring generated web pages.  However your mileage may vary.